# Android: change dialog's content depending on each listener is triggered

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an activity with 5 buttons, each one with a TextView bellow, I want to show a "settings" Dialog Fragment after onLongClick for each button that allows the user to change its corresponding TextView.
This is how I call the fragment on each onLongClick:

```
fm = getFragmentManager();
myFragment = new Fragment_Edit();

FirstButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                myFragment.show(fm, "theFragment");
                return false;
        }
});
```

The Fragment has one EditText, one Button, and the default code.
I need the dialog's EditText that appears when I click the FirstButton to change the TextView under the first Button; the dialog's EditText that appears when I click the third Button to change the TextView under the third Button, you get the point. Detailed explanations are welcomed.

EDIT: Without having to create 5 fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

1. Pass the id of the textview to your fragment
2. Fetch the id in the fragment, then get a reference to the textview via the `getActivity()`.

Something like below would work:

```
fm = getFragmentManager();
myFragment = new Fragment_Edit();

FirstButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            // Pass the id of view to fragment
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt("id", v.getId());
            myFragment.setArgument(data);

            myFragment.show(fm, "theFragment");
            return false;
    }
});
```

Then in `onCreate()` of your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the data
    if (getArguments() != null) {

        Bundle data = getArguments();
        int id = data.getInt("id");

        // Get the corresponding textview from parent activity
        textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(id);
    }
}
```

You can either set the parent TextView with this approach, or set up an **interface** to communicate with the parent activity. Let me know if you want the second (interface) approach.

---

UPDATE:

Ok, I will guide you through this design step by step:

1. Declare the `TextView` in your fragment just like you would for the `EditText`. So something like `private TextView textView;`
2. Next, initialise the textView in your `onCreate()` in the fragment just like the code I posted above.
3. Now, where does your `EditText` participate? Well, it is used to get the text from the user. You will use the text user entered into your `EditText` to set the `textView`. So something like the following:

   `String newText = editText.getText().toString();`

   `textView.setText(newText);`

---

So you've got it working now, and yes you would need to do the same for all your buttons. What you can do is write a method that does the job for you, and just pass in the buttons you want:

```
private void addOnClickListener(Button button, myFragment) {
    button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            // Pass the id of view to fragment
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt("id", v.getId());
            myFragment.setArgument(data);

            myFragment.show(fm, "theFragment");
            return false;
    }
});
```

Then just do:

```
addOnClickListener(FirstButton, myFragment);
addOnClickListener(SecondButton, myFragment);
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, seems like the right way, but I have a few questions about it. when you say `data.putString("id", v.getId());` woudn't it  pass the Button's view's ID? I changed it to this `String.valueOf(FirstText.getId()))` which should work, plus, this `myFragment.setArgument(data);` is giving an error

Comment: My apologies, it should be `data.putInt("id", v.getId())`

Comment: That solved the error, but what ID is `v.getID()` passing?

Comment: `View.getId()` returns the id you set for the view in your layout xml file :)

Comment: Btw you can kindly accept it as answer if it was helpful to you. Good luck coding!

Comment: I'm still not making this work `textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(id);`

Comment: How do I initialize `textView` and do I replace `(id)` with `R.id.TextViewID` TextViewID beeing the ID of the TextView i want to change. And where does the EditText in the fragment participate?

Comment: Don't mind the the question about replacing `(id)`, I got that now

Comment: Cool, please see my updated answer. I will guide you through how to approach this design.

Comment: Ok so when I long click on the button it crashes, here is my onLongClick: `Bundle data = new Bundle();
 data.putInt("id", FirstText.getId());
 myFragment.setArguments(data);

 myFragment.show(fm, "theFragment");
 return false;`

Comment: The dialog's onCreate:
`if (getArguments() != null) {

            Bundle data = getArguments();
            int id = data.getInt("id");

            mTextView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(id);

            DoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String newText = mEditText.getText().toString();
                    mTextView.setText(newText);
                    getDialog().dismiss();
                }
            });

        }`

Comment: Where did you initialise `mEditText`?

Comment: I just did, inside onCreateView, but it's still crashing

Comment: When it crashes, what error do you see in the log? can you post it?

Comment: Like I said before, you need to initialise your button. The log complains that your button is null.

Comment: Try and move your `DoneButton.setOncli....` method from `onCreate()` to `onCreatView()`, right after you initialise your button.

Comment: I do have my button initiated: `DoneButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.AlrightButton);`

Comment: Yes you do, then add `DoneButton.setOnClick...` method right below it. because `onCreate()` is called before `onCreatView()`, so when you call `DoneButton` in `onCreate()`, it has not been initialised yet.

Comment: Ok it's working! Now creating a diffrent bundle for each button will work?

Comment: I just had to change which Text's ID is getting passed on each onLongClick :)

Comment: No worries, glad i helped :)

Comment: Perhaps you can help me with one more thing, after I change the TextView through the dialog, I need to update the TextView's text in it's SharedPrefs, how can I access the sharedPrefs in the dialog?

Comment: Remember how we called `getActivity()` to get a reference to the parent activity class? The same logic can be applied here. `SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: Alright, and what is the "preference" key refering to?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: It's 1 am here...i need to sleep :)